SQL Server query executes very slow
I have the following query that takes minutes to get executed. When I started writing this query, uptil TVVA5.VVA_VAL it was OK but when I introduced TVVA6 it became slow and when I introduced TVVA7 it became slower and keeps becoming slower as I add TVVA columns. I found that until any 5 TVVA columns it works well. Any idea to optimize this query.
SELECT 
                [TCRD].[CRD_REQ_ID] AS [requestId],
                [TCTP].[CTP_CDE] AS cardType,
                [TCHD].[CHD_COD_EXT] AS codeCardHolder,
                [TCHD].[CHD_FRST_NAMES] AS firstNames,
                [TCHD].[CHD_INI] AS initials,
                [TCHD].[CHD_PFX_LST_NAME] AS prefixLastName,
                [TCHD].[CHD_LST_NAME] AS lastName,
                [TCHD].[CHD_TTL_PFX] AS titlePrefix,
                [TCHD].[CHD_TTL_SFX] AS titleSuffix,
                [TCHD].[CHD_DOB] dateOfBirth,
                [TCRD].[CRD_VAL_DTE] AS cardExpiryDate,
                [TCRD].[CRD_ISS_DTE] AS cardIssueDate,
                [TCHD].[CHD_NAT_CODE] AS natCode,
                [TCHD].[CGD_GDR_CDE] AS genderCode,

                [TPIC].[PIC_VAL] AS picture,
                [TSIG].[SIG_VAL] AS [signature],

                [TCRD].[CRD_NAME_ON_CARD] AS nameOnCard,
                [TORG].[ORG_CDE] AS organizationCode,
                [TNAT].[NAT_DESC_AR] AS nationalityArabic,
                TORG.ORG_FULL_NAME issuingAuthority,

                TVVA1.VVA_VAL nameArabic,
                TVVA2.VVA_VAL docmentType,
                TVVA3.VVA_VAL docmentNumber,
                TVVA4.VVA_VAL passportNumber,
                TVVA5.VVA_VAL phoneNumber,
                TVVA6.VVA_VAL professionEnglish,
                TVBV1.VBV_VAL passportImage,
                TVVA7.VVA_VAL cardPersonalizationDate,
                TVVA8.VVA_VAL printerSerialNumber,
                TVVA9.VVA_VAL placeOfBirthArabic,
                TVVA10.VVA_VAL addressInQatarArabic,
                TVVA11.VVA_VAL sponsorNameEnglish,
                TVVA12.VVA_VAL sponsorNameArabic,
                TVVA13.VVA_VAL residencyType
            FROM        
                TCHD                
            INNER JOIN
                TCRD
            ON
                [TCHD].[CHD_ID] = [TCRD].[CRD_CHD_ID]
            INNER JOIN
                TCTP
            ON
                [TCRD].[CRD_CTP_ID] = [TCTP].[CTP_ID]
            INNER JOIN
                TNAT
            ON
                [TCHD].[CHD_NAT_CODE] = [TNAT].[NAT_CODE]
            INNER JOIN
                TORG
            ON
                [TCRD].[CRD_ORG_ID] = [TORG].[ORG_ID]
            INNER JOIN
                TPIC                        
                cross apply (select [TPIC].[PIC_VAL] AS '*' for xml path('')) P ([picture])
            ON
                [TCRD].[CRD_ID] = [TPIC].[PIC_CRD_ID]
            INNER JOIN              
                TSIG
                cross apply (select [TSIG].[SIG_VAL] AS '*' for xml path('')) S ([signature])
            ON
                [TCRD].[CRD_ID] = [TSIG].[SIG_CRD_ID]
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA1
            ON
                TVVA1.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID 
            AND
                TVVA1.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'NAME_ARABIC' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA2
            ON
                TVVA2.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID 
            AND 
                TVVA2.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'DOCUMENT_TYPE' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA3
            ON
                TVVA3.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID
            AND 
                TVVA3.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'DOCUMENT_NUMBER' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA4
            ON
                TVVA4.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID
            AND 
                TVVA4.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'PASSPORT_NUMBER' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA5
            ON
                TVVA5.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID
            AND 
                TVVA5.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'PHONE_NUMBER' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA6
            ON
                TVVA6.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID
            AND 
                TVVA6.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'PROFESSION_ENGLISH' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA7
            ON
                TVVA7.VVA_PK_VAL = TCRD.CRD_ID
            AND 
                TVVA7.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'CARD_PERSONALIZATION_DATE' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVBV TVBV1
                cross apply (select TVBV1.VBV_VAL AS '*' for xml path('')) PP ([passportImage])
            ON
                TVBV1.VBV_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID      
            AND 
                TVBV1.VBV_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'PASSPORT_IMAGE' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA8
            ON
                TVVA8.VVA_PK_VAL = TCRD.CRD_ID
            AND 
                TVVA8.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'PRINTER_SERIAL_NUMBER' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA9
            ON
                TVVA9.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID
            AND 
                TVVA9.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'PLACE_OF_BIRTH_ARABIC' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA10
            ON
                TVVA10.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID
            AND 
                TVVA10.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'ADDRESS_IN_QATAR_ARABIC' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA11
            ON
                TVVA11.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID
            AND 
                TVVA11.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'SPONSOR_NAME_ENGLISH' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA12
            ON
                TVVA12.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID
            AND 
                TVVA12.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'SPONSOR_NAME_ARABIC' )
            INNER JOIN
                TVVA TVVA13
            ON
                TVVA13.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID
            AND 
                TVVA13.VVA_DVR_ID = (SELECT TDVR.DVR_ID FROM TDVR WHERE TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'RESIDENCY_TYPE' )
            WHERE                                       
                [TCRD].[CRD_REQ_ID] = 10720

PasteThePlan

For SQL performance questions you need to provide the table structure, index definitions and the execution plan (using Paste The Plan). In SQL, a query is a logical problem statement, how SQL Server translates that into an execution plan is completely database specific, hence why in general its not possible to offer performance advice based on a query itself.

You can rewrite your joins first, perhaps it will solve the problem already. The old school joins have been obsolete since 1992, might as well join the modern times. Probably the index of TVVA is bad too, but hard to say, you should post the query plan using https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Here's the query plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bk-dmkgxA

[edit] any clarifications into your question.

You definitely need to try what siggemannen suggested also.

Then look into those clustered index scans and see if an index can convert them into a seek.

@DaleK I have re-written the joins and edited my original post. Updated execution plan as below:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sk4FQ-elC
The result is almost the same, after 5 TVVAs the query starts responding slower and slower.

Use conditional aggregation in a subquery, rather than many joins  https://dbfiddle.uk/hRVcQWK1

Instead of joining again and again for every possible VVA_VAL, use conditional aggregation inside an APPLY or a join on a derived table.
        SELECT 
            [TCRD].[CRD_REQ_ID] AS [requestId],
            [TCTP].[CTP_CDE] AS cardType,
            [TCHD].[CHD_COD_EXT] AS codeCardHolder,
            [TCHD].[CHD_FRST_NAMES] AS firstNames,
            [TCHD].[CHD_INI] AS initials,
            [TCHD].[CHD_PFX_LST_NAME] AS prefixLastName,
            [TCHD].[CHD_LST_NAME] AS lastName,
            [TCHD].[CHD_TTL_PFX] AS titlePrefix,
            [TCHD].[CHD_TTL_SFX] AS titleSuffix,
            [TCHD].[CHD_DOB] dateOfBirth,
            [TCRD].[CRD_VAL_DTE] AS cardExpiryDate,
            [TCRD].[CRD_ISS_DTE] AS cardIssueDate,
            [TCHD].[CHD_NAT_CODE] AS natCode,
            [TCHD].[CGD_GDR_CDE] AS genderCode,

            [TPIC].[PIC_VAL] AS picture,
            [TSIG].[SIG_VAL] AS [signature],

            [TCRD].[CRD_NAME_ON_CARD] AS nameOnCard,
            [TORG].[ORG_CDE] AS organizationCode,
            [TNAT].[NAT_DESC_AR] AS nationalityArabic,
            TORG.ORG_FULL_NAME issuingAuthority,

            TVVA.*
        FROM        
            TCHD                
        INNER JOIN
            TCRD ON TCHD.CHD_ID = TCRD.CRD_CHD_ID
        INNER JOIN
            TCTP ON TCRD.CRD_CTP_ID = TCTP.CTP_ID
        INNER JOIN
            TNAT ON TCHD.CHD_NAT_CODE = TNAT.NAT_CODE
        INNER JOIN
            TORG ON TCRD.CRD_ORG_ID = TORG.ORG_ID
        INNER JOIN TPIC                        
            cross apply (select [TPIC].[PIC_VAL] AS '*' for xml path('')) P ([picture])
        ON TCRD.CRD_ID = TPIC.PIC_CRD_ID
        INNER JOIN              
            TSIG
            cross apply (select [TSIG].[SIG_VAL] AS '*' for xml path('')) S ([signature])
        ON TCRD.CRD_ID = TSIG.SIG_CRD_ID
        CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'nameArabic' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) nameArabic,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'docmentType' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) docmentType,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'docmentNumber' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) docmentNumber,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'passportNumber' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) passportNumber,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'phoneNumber' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) phoneNumber,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'professionEnglish' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) professionEnglish,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'passportImage' THEN TVBV.VBV_VAL END) passportImage,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'cardPersonalizationDate' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) cardPersonalizationDate,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'printerSerialNumber' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) printerSerialNumber,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'placeOfBirthArabic' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) placeOfBirthArabic,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'addressInQatarArabic' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) addressInQatarArabic,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'sponsorNameEnglish' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) sponsorNameEnglish,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'sponsorNameArabic' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) sponsorNameArabic,
            MIN(CASE WHEN TDVR.DVR_NAME = 'residencyType' THEN TVVA.VVA_VAL END) residencyType
          FROM TVVA
          JOIN TDVR ON TVVA.VVA_DVR_ID = TDVR.DVR_ID
          WHERE
            TVVA.VVA_PK_VAL = TCHD.CHD_ID 
        ) TVVA
        WHERE                                       
            [TCRD].[CRD_REQ_ID] = 10720

